# Parsing XML using PHP giving me NULL when printing

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am pretty new to php but i have some programming knowledge. I am trying to parse information from an XML but for some reason it is not working.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$feed = implode(file('https://recruit.visma.com/External/Feeds/AssignmentList.ashx?guidGroup=221caebb-3836-4036-8c83-edd6e630ec79'));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$jobs = reformat(json_decode($json,TRUE));

  function reformat($jobs){
    //$vacancies = $jobs['Assigmentlist'];
    $vacancies = $jobs['Assignmentlist'];
    var_dump(($vacancies));
    $res = array();

    // if(count($vacancies) > 0) {
    //  foreach($vacancies AS $vacancy) {
    //     //$item["title"] = $vacancy["Assigments"]["Assigment"]["AssigmentTitle"];
    //     //$item["link"] = $vacancy["Assigments"]["Assigment"]["ReadMoreUrl"];
    //     //$item["date"] = $vacancy["Assigments"]["Assigment"]["ApplicationEndDate"];
    //     $item["title"] = $vacancy["Versions"]["Version"]["Title"];
    //     $item["link"] = $vacancy["Departments"]["Department"]["VacancyURL"];
    //     $item["date"] = $vacancy["@attributes"]["date_end"];//$vacancy["Versions"]["Version"]["ApplicationDeadline"] ?: "Ej funnen";
    //     array_push($res, $item);
    //   }
    // }

    }

?>
```

Why is my dump giving me NULL? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML is eating your top level element, so you're getting a collection of Assignments elements.

[image]

So what you're expecting in `$jobs['Assignmentlist']`is actually already in `$jobs`

**Edit**: XPath example

```
<?php
//Get the contents of the file
$feed = file_get_contents('https://recruit.visma.com/External/Feeds/AssignmentList.ashx?guidGroup=221caebb-3836-4036-8c83-edd6e630ec79');

//Instantiate DOMDocument and load the XML String
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($feed);

//Instantiate DOMXPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

//XPath query for all of our Assignment elements
$query = '/Assignmentlist/Assignments/Assignment';

//Run the query
$jobs  = $xpath->query($query);

//Format using our reformat function
$formatted = reformat($jobs, $xpath);

/**
 * Convert Assignment nodes into our tuples
 * @param DOMNodeList $jobs
 * @param DOMXPath $xpath
 * @return array
 */
function reformat(DOMNodeList $jobs, DOMXPath $xpath)
{
    $res = [];

    foreach ($jobs AS $vacancy)
    {
        $res[] = [
            'title' => $xpath->query('Localization/AssignmentLoc/AssignmentTitle', $vacancy)->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $xpath->query('ReadMoreUrl', $vacancy)->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $xpath->query('PublishEndDate', $vacancy)->item(0)->nodeValue
        ];
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: True, but why is `$vacancies = $jobs['Assignments']["Assignment"]` returning me correct result but going one level deeper it gives me NULL? `$vacancies = $jobs['Assignments']["Assignment"]["Localization"];` i know its not the question but i need to access that variable please explain?

Comment: Because you're using SimpleXML. Look at the structure - inside Assignment, there is another SimpleXML object. You need to look in $vacancy['Assignment'][0]['Localization']

Also, this is a really messy way to do this, I recommend you look into DOMXpath (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). It may look intimidating but it's easier and cleaner than this approach.

Comment: But i am using a foreach loop to iterate through all the rows that contains Localization? Still not working. If possible could you write an example either with xpath or with my version to access Localization elements?

Comment: Added XPath example

Comment: My example also worked, i missed AssignmentLoc element. thanks!